# How to apply ActiveModel::Serializer to a custom object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, active-model-serializers

If I specify simple array of ActiveModel objects serializer works:

```
format.json { render json: @childs, each_serializer: ItemSerializer }
```

But I need to respond with JSON with additional fields, such as `parent_id`, etc.

```
{parent_id: 15, childs: @childs}
```

Any idea how to achieve it?

**item_serializer.rb**

```
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :parent_id
end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
 def roots
    @childs = Item.where(parent_id: 15)
    respond_to do |format|
        # serializer below does not work...
        format.json { render json: {parent_id: 15, childs: @childs}, each_serializer: ItemSerializer }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay! I figure it out! Hope it helps someone else!

```
respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json:
                { parent_id: parent_id, childs: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@childs, each_serializer: ItemSerializer) }
            }
        end
```